# how to map a collection of enums in spring-data for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

spring-data 1.0.0.M3 with MongoDB. How come spring can map this class:

```
import org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.index.IndexDirection;
import org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class EnumsMapper { 
  private IndexDirection d = IndexDirection.ASCENDING;
}
```

and fails with this one:

```
import org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.index.IndexDirection;
import org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.mapping.Document;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Document
public class EnumsMapper { 
  List<IndexDirection> list_enum_test = Arrays.asList(
      new IndexDirection[] {IndexDirection.ASCENDING});

}
```

with a:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.index.IndexDirection
```

The same happens with other collections (sets, ...), and also arrays. Obviously spring can map this enum, so writing a mapper doesn't solve the problem. Is this a bug or there's a way to map a collection (set/map) holding enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you discovered a bug :). Here's [the bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATADOC-209), here's [the fix](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-document/commit/e1daf36ed82407f680e7b7c4777e0bc3daf593f8). Snapshot binaries deployed to our Maven repo. Feel free to give it a try and add comments to the ticket in case you're still missing something.

Comment: Both links are not found.